# something about “from sys import argv”

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

I use PyCharm to run my code but get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/haha.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Comment: What command line did you use to execute your script? If you didn't provide any command line arguments the `argv` vector will only contain the name of the executable/script.

Comment: Link to the documentation: You need to pass at least 3 arguments to get the script running correctly: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Comment: And if you actually *provide* parameters? `python haha.py foo bar baz`? Also, note that *"something about ..."* is so vague a title as to be completely pointless.